# Sound setting for guest user account (Yosemite)

Tags: audio, macos

I have two accounts: primary and guest. In the primary account headphones is using as an output audio device and for the guest account USB is using. Previously all outputs are configured automatically. I mean when I enter in primary account headphones sets as default audio and when I enter as guest USB sets as default. I didn't make any manual switching. After update to Yosemite, the guest account was to inherit the settings of the main. It is possible to set the audio output by default for all accounts except one of them?

**UPD:** I did some tests and came to the conclusion that the system now does not remember settings for each user, and applies the current setting of audio output for all accounts.

Comment: that would be a step back in customer friendliness :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similer issue.  I posted about it here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/27369846#27369846

I can copy that post here if its appropriate and doesn't violate terms etc.?

Comment: Normally since this doesn't answer the question, you would add a link like that as a comment to the question.  It's defintily not an answer.   FWIW. see the OP's edit, it looks like he did some testing and has more info.

Comment: Thanks.  New here so still learning the right way to share info.